# Customizing spring data JPA constructor exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to spring data and I'm trying to customize it. here is what I tried so far:
My base repository interface

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity<PK>, PK extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, PK> {
}
```

And it's implementation

```
public class BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity<PK>, PK extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, PK>
  implements IBaseRepository<T, PK> {

public BaseRepository(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
  super(domainClass, em);
}
}
```

Now I want to have standalone repository class for users so

```
public interface IUserRepository extends IBaseRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

And

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User, Long> implements IUserRepository {

  UserRepository(Class<User> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
  super(domainClass, em);
  }

}
```

But I got this exception:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.bia2hd.dao.impl.UserRepository required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're implementing the repository yourself?

Comment: Yes there is, actually I want to add more functionality to my repository. that's why I have extend my class from `SimpleJpaRepository`.

Comment: What sort of functionality specifically?

Comment: for instance, I want to execute a native query on user table join with another unmapped table.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: @JamesRiady Yeah, you should define all your Entity classes as bean. but personally, I've changed my mind.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure this is the answer that helps people in future but solved my problem, just added the following method in each service:

```
@Bean
@Override
public Class<User> getDomain() {
  return User.class;
}
```